# Update query not working in PHP and not leaving any errors behind

Tags: php, html, sql-update

I have created a database named editor and table named editorNB. i have attached my table details with this post.
Also im attaching my both php file and html file.

PROBLEM: the problem im having is that  I am abeto insert and delete wit hthis code however when i update it directly sends  me to page where i  want to go after "Successfully updated". BUT it is just not udpating. at all.

Field    Type        Null Key Default Extra
user_uid varchar(256) NO       NULL 
subject  varchar(300) NO       NULL
content  text         NO       NULL
entry_id int(11)      NO  PRI  NULL  auto_increment
date     date         NO      NULL

```js
<?php
    session_start();

    if ($_SESSION['u_uid']) {

    } else {
        header("location: http://localhost/Project%20NB/signupnb.php");
        exit();
    }
    
    $user    = $_SESSION['u_uid'];
    $subject = "";
    $entry   = "";
    $update  = FALSE;
    $id      = 0;
    
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $date    = date("M/d/y");
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $entry   = $_POST['editor'];
        $conn2 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
        mysqli_Select_db($conn2, "editor") or die("connot connect to the database");
    
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn2, "INSERT INTO `editornb` (`user_uid`,`subject`, `content`, `date`) values ('" . $user . "','" . $subject . "','" . $entry . "','" . $date . "')");
        $er   = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    
        if ($er == TRUE) {
            print '<script> alert("Sucessfully Inserted!!!");</script>';
            header("location:http://localhost/Project%20NB/projectNB.php");
        } else {
            header("location:http://localhost/Project%20NB/projectNB.php");
            exit();
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
        $id      = $_POST['edit'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $content = $_POST['editor'];
        $conn2 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
        mysqli_Select_db($conn2, "editor") or die("connot connect to the database");
            
        $updatenew = "UPDATE `editornb` SET content='" . $content . "',`subject`='" . $subject . "' WHERE entry_id='" . $id . "'";
        $query     = mysqli_query($conn2, $updatenew);
        $er        = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            
        if ($query == TRUE) {
            print '<script> alert("Sucessfully updated!!!");</script>';
            header("location:http://localhost/Project%20NB/projectNB.php");
        } else {
            header("location:http://localhost/Project%20NB/editor/temptextarea.php");
            exit();
        }        
    }

    if (isset($_GET['delid'])) {
        $id     = $_GET['delid'];
        $sql    = "DELETE FROM editornb WHERE entry_id= '$id' ";
        $answer = mysqli_query($conn2, $sql);
        print '<script> alert("Sucessfully deleted!!!");</script>';        
    }

    session_abort();
```

```html
<?php
    $conn2=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
    mysqli_select_db($conn2,"editor") or die("connot connect to the database");

    include('php_file.php');
    session_start();             

    if(isset($_GET['edit'])) {
        $id = $_GET['edit'];
        $update = TRUE;
        $query = "SELECT * from `editornb` where entry_id='$id'";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn2, $query);

        if (count($result) == 1) {
            $n = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $subject = $n['subject'];
            $content = $n['content'];           
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> CK EDITOR </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/Project%20NB/editor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/Project%20NB/editor/fontawesome/fontawesome-free-5.0.6/web-fonts-with-css/css/fontawesome.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/Project%20NB/editor/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="http://localhost/Project%20NB/editor/textareaNB.php"> Home </a>

    <br>
    <form action="http://localhost/Project%20NB/editor/php_file.php" method="POST" id="editorForm">
        <input type="text" name="subject" value="<?php echo $subject; ?>"> 
        <textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor" name="editor"><?php if(isset($content)) echo $content; ?></textarea>
        <br>
        <?php if ($update == true): ?>
        <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-sucess">Update</button>
        <?php else: ?>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sucess">Submit</button> 
        <?php endif ?>
    </form>
    
    <?php
        if (isset($alertMessage))
            echo $alertMessage;
    ?>
    <br> 
    <div class="search">
        <form method="post" action="search_go.php"  id="searchform"> 
         <input  type="text" name="name"> 
         <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"> 
     </form> 
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table">
        <tr>
            <th> ID</i></a></th>
            <th> DATE</th>
            <th> Subject</th>
            <th> Update</th> 
            <th> Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            $count = 1;
            $user = ($_SESSION['u_uid']);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `editornb` where user_uid='".$user."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn2, $query);
            $result_check = mysqli_num_rows ($result);
            $date = date("M/d/y");
        
            if ($result_check > 0) {
                while ($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {                 
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" .$count."</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row["date"]. "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row["subject"]."</td>"; 
                    echo '<td><a href="http://localhost/Project%20NB/editor/temptextarea.php?edit='.$row['entry_id'].'" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"> 
                        <span class="fa fa-edit"></span> </a></td>';
                    echo '<td><a href="http://localhost/Project%20NB/editor/php_file.php?delid='.$row['entry_id'].'" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                        </a></td>';
                    echo "</tr>";
                    $count++; 
                }                
            }
        ?>    
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd start by checking for errors first.

Comment: that's the thing, i am not getting any error which confuses me even more.

Comment: I don't see any here. Either php's error reporting or `mysqli_error($conn2)`. You only assume there are no errors.

Comment: Not a php guy but...Why you don't have quotes on your table in the delete but do have on the update? "DELETE FROM editornb...."UPDATE 'editornb '

Comment: the quotes is not making any differene i tried that too.

Comment: I would check if the user im using to connect to the database has update right! NVM  your using root

Comment: And maybe you are using the wrong single quote. arround subject

Comment: echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";

Comment: i did tried from database it was working just fine. the query that im using here is exactly same.@MadeInDreams  And also the rowcount is  doing either

Comment: First of all you shouldn't build SQL statements that way.  For security reasons you should be binding parameters to the sql statement.  But just for trying to make this work can you try and remove the quotes between $id since it may be parsed as string instead of integer:
`$id = (int) $_POST['edit'];`
`$updatenew="UPDATE editornb SET content='".$content."', subject='".$subject."' WHERE entry_id= ". $id;`